# Counting the number of values that are more than 60 for each row

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    location   td1_2019  td2_2019  td3_2019 td4_2019 td1_2020 td2_2020 td3_2020 td4_2020
1  a           50        55        60       58       63        55        60       58
2  b           45        65        57       50       61        66        62       59
3  c           61        66        62       59       45        65        57       50
```

here, td1_2019 = temperature day1 in 2019 ... and so on

I want count the number of days temperature was above 60 for both 2019 and 2020 for each location. I want the table to look like the following:

```
   location   2019       2020  
1  a           1          2        
2  b           1          3        
3  c           3          1
```

I am using R, so I would prefer a solution in R. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: can you use `dput()` for data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -location, 
    names_to = c("day", "year"), 
    names_pattern = "td(\\d)_(\\d{4})", 
    values_to = "temperature"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(year, location) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(temperature >= 60)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "year", values_from = "n")
```

A Base R solution

```
nms <- names(df1)
cond <- df1 >= 60
Reduce(
  function(out, y) `[[<-`(out, y, value = rowSums(cond[, which(grepl(y, nms))])), 
  c("2019", "2020"), 
  init = df1[, "location", drop = FALSE]
)
```

Output

```
  location `2019` `2020`
  <chr>     <int>  <int>
1 a             1      2
2 b             1      3
3 c             3      1
```

Assume that `df1` looks like this

```
> df1
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  location td1_2019 td2_2019 td3_2019 td4_2019 td1_2020 td2_2020 td3_2020 td4_2020
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 a              50       55       60       58       63       55       60       58
2 b              45       65       57       50       61       66       62       59
3 c              61       66       62       59       45       65       57       50
```

Comment: Hi @mgdata, glad to know that. If this or any other answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work: I think you want something more year wise.

```
> library(dplyr) 
> temp %>% pivot_longer(-location, names_to = c('td', 'year'), names_pattern = '(.*)_(.*)', values_to = 'temp') %>% 
+   filter(temp >= 60) %>% count(location, year, name = 'Count') %>% 
+   pivot_wider(location, names_from = year, values_from = Count, values_fill = list(Count = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  location `2019` `2020`
  <chr>     <int>  <int>
1 a             1      2
2 b             1      3
3 c             3      1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tidy solution. Just as in the other solutions posted (which are very nice), a key move is to get the data in a long format using `pivot_longer()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-location) %>%
  mutate(year = str_sub(name, -2)) %>%
  group_by(location, year) %>%
  mutate(above60 = sum(value >= 60)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(location, year, above60) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = above60)

#   location  `19`  `20`
#   <chr>    <int> <int>
# 1 a            1     2
# 2 b            1     3
# 3 c            3     1
```

**data**

```
structure(list(location = c("a", "b", "c"), td1_2019 = c(50, 
45, 61), td2_2019 = c(55, 65, 66), td3_2019 = c(60, 57, 62), 
    td4_2019 = c(58, 50, 59), td1_2020 = c(63, 61, 45), td2_2020 = c(55, 
    66, 65), td3_2020 = c(60, 62, 57), td4_2020 = c(58, 59, 50
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
cbind(
  df[1],
  list2DF(
    lapply(
      split.default(
        as.data.frame(df[-1] >= 60),
        gsub(".*?(\\d+)$", "\\1", names(df)[-1],
          perl = TRUE
        )
      ),
      rowSums
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  location 2019 2020
1        a    1    2
2        b    1    3
3        c    3    1
```